# D3 barchart on Firefox Android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, firefox-for-android, javascript

It seems I that I can't load this [d3 barchart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) on an android phone (android version 4.4.2) and on Firefox browser. Firefox on Android has javascript enabled (checked from about:config) and also the built in android browser and Chrome also is able to load the same page and show the visual. So it has to do something with Firefox. Any ideas what to check?

Attached is a screenshot of the [d3 barchart page](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) loaded in Firefox for Android

[image: screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge image</sub>

Comment: I have no problems loading the page in Chrome and Opera and UC Browser. Did you change anything in the `about:config`? Could you post us the screenshot on how the page is displayed in your Firefox Android browser?

Comment: @Lucky : how can I post a screenshot in this comment? No haven't changed anything in `about : config`.

Comment: you can click [edit] link on your question anytime you want to post and update or add additional information. Look at [How to upload an image to a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: @Lucky : Thank you. I was trying to post the image on the comment, whereas it should go on the original post... So I do not know why I am getting this. Are you able to load the link on a Firefox in Android?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Firefox browser on my android. Could your reset the browser cache/settings and check? Also please visit this url to find [if javascript enabled](http://enable-javascript.com/)

Comment: @Lucky : History and cache erased. Firefox started with a `Welcome to Firefox!` prompt, as if it was newly installed. Javascript is enabled. D3 bar chart page in question visited but still visual does not show, leaving me with the same attached screenshot in the post question.

Comment: Have you checked the [Request Desktop Site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-change-desktop-view-firefox-android) under Menu and tried loading the page?

Comment: @Lucky : Checked `Request Desktop Site` for Firefox on Android but still visual on page does not show. Uninstalled and reinstalled firefox and when started for the first time also checked `Request Desktop Site` but problem persists. Unchecked also `Request Desktop Site', with the newly installed Firefox and again no luck...

Comment: As [Firelord mentioned](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/119589/27149) he has not problems loading the page in his Firefox broswer. Are you sure you are using the updated version? or Are you using the Firefox beta?Please mention your version and are you using any other mobile-addons? If yes please uninstall the mobile addons and check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in Firefox. I have tested the said website on Firefox v35.0.2 and v40.0. It shows the graph as good as it does on Desktop.

[image: IMG:]

If you are running the latest release yet facing that issue then it implies that your Firefox's configuration is messed up. I've [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) addon installed and I allowed `cloudflare.com` and `ocks.org` in it, since both are needed to show that chart.

I suggest you open Guest mode in the browser and visit that site. It should definitely help in understanding whether it's Firefox itself or your custom configuration that's causing the issue.